# Laptop new nic hard blocked no switch or bios settings

Tags: networking, drivers, iwlwifi

I wanted to have wifi5 in my laptop -soney vaio fit svf1531- I got an intel Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6230 pcie card. However, I get the message no wifi adapter found in the wifi settings.

The laptop has not wifi switches and no network options in the bios.

**dmesg:**

```
[ 1083.143780] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: reporting RF_KILL (radio disabled)
[ 1083.143795] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
```

**rfkill:**

```
2: phy1: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

**lspci**

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6230 [Rainbow Peak] (rev 34)
```

Comment: Have you searched for "hard blocked" here? There are several posts asking the same thing with various possible solutions.

Comment: yeah I tried many things, looks like the card itself had an issue since I only managed to unblock it by masking pin 20!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying every fix I could find, it only worked by masking pin 20 of the wifi card, like the attached photo.

I assume that means the card itself has an issue, or just because it is an old model. Anyway it works now so I am happy.

The solution can be found here:
https://gsid.in/using-old-mini-pcie-wlan-cards-in-modern-laptops/

Comment: ok I can't attach a photo, but the photo is in the link